# grouping children in variable by sibling element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have some XML data similar to the following, stored *inside a variable* in xslt 1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ItemCollection>
  <Item>
    <Number>1</Number>
    <Data>string 1</Data>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Number>1</Number>
    <Data>string 2</Data>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Number>2</Number>
    <Data>string 3</Data>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Number>2</Number>
    <Data>string 3</Data>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Number>3</Number>
    <Data>string 4</Data>
  </Item>
</ItemCollection>
```

This variable is called `$collection`.

I want to transform the data so it will have a structure as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ItemCollection>
  <Item>
    <Number>1</Number>
    <Data>string 1</Data>
    <Data>string 2</Data>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Number>2</Number>
    <Data>string 3</Data>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Number>3</Number>
    <Data>string 4</Data>
  </Item>
</ItemCollection>
```

That is: `Data`'s who have the same sibling `Number` (in value) should be grouped together. Duplicates of `Item`'s should be removed entirely, if the `Number` and the `Data` both are similar. In the original XML, each `Item` has *exactly* one `Number` and one `Data` - I want to change this so it will still only have one `Number`, but several `Data`.

The XML data is, as said, *inside a variable*, which lies above. I've tried different things such as using two `xsl:for-each` to iterate the variable twice (using `exsl:node-set($collection)//Item`), but this only yielded a sorted order of the data, which is not of much use.

This is the XSLT I currently have (only a snippet, can post more if necessary)

```
<xsl:variable name="collection" select="'XMl DATA'"/>
<xsl:variable name="final">
  <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($collection)//Item">
    <xsl:variable name="outer" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($collection)//Item">
      <xsl:variable name="inner" select="."/>
      <xsl:if test="$inner = $outer">
        <Item>
          <xsl:value-of select="$outer/Number"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$inner/Data"/>
        </Item>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:copy-of select="$final" />
```

Edit:

Thanks alot, for the answer. I realized that the result contains duplicates like so:

```
<Item>
    <Number>2039205</Number>
    <Data>String 1</Data>
    <Data>String 1</Data>
    <Data>String 1</Data>
</tns:Item>
```

Is there an easy way o remove these as well? I tried declaring another `xsl:key`

`<xsl:key name="item-by-data" match="Item" use="Data"/>` and then do:

```
  <xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Number| key('item-by-data', Number)/Data[generate-id() = generate-id(key('item-by-data', Data)[1])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

But that removed all of the items, and not just the duplicates.

Comment: This doesn't make sense: `<xsl:variable name="collection" select="'XMl DATA'"/>` It shows that the variable contains the literal string "XMl DATA" and not what you claim. Why must you use this variable in the first place anyway? Or the `$final` variable? Why not process the actual input and write directly to the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml) on the node-set you get with e.g. `<xsl:param name="col-ns" select="exsl:node-set($collection)"/>`, that is, define a key

```
<xsl:key name="item-by-number" match="Item" use="Number"/>
```

then have

```
<xsl:template match="ItemCollection">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('item-by-number', Number)[1])]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="Item">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="Number | key('item-by-number', Number)/Data"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then you just need to have `<xsl:apply-templates select="$col-ns/node()"/>` in the place where you need to transform your content.

Complete sample is at http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJc.

If you also want to eliminate duplicate `Data` then you can use `<xsl:key name="numbered-items-by-data" match="Item" use="concat(Number, '|', Data)"/>` and

```
<xsl:template match="Item">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="Number | key('item-by-number', Number)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('numbered-items-by-data', concat(Number, '|', Data))[1])]/Data"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

a sample is at http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJc/2.

Comment: I edited the question since the result contains duplicates of the `Data.`

Comment: Please edit your input and result samples as well so that we have some data showing the problem and to write code against.